# Why is my python list vertical?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Using python 3 and jupyter notebook (I have to, for class).

I have a function that creates a list by looping a number of times and appending a randomly chosen element from another list. But when I use the function, the list it gives displays each element on a new line. Why? Can I change it?

The code:

```
def create_board(length=32,seed=0,types=2):
"""
Creates a one-dimensional game board of randomly placed
letters, using as many as are specified.
"""

    if types>26:
        print("No, try a number smaller than 27.")

    else:    

        board = []
        letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M",
                  "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]


        for i in range(length):
            val=random.randint(0,(types-1))
            board.append(letters[val])


        return board
```

And then both

```
    print(create_board())
```

and

```
    create_board()
    board
```

put out the created list, but with each element on a new line:

['B',

'B',

'A',

'B',

'A',

and so on.

Comment: That's just Jupyter trying to display the list in a more readable manner (and not succeeding). The list is the same regardless of how many lines Jupyter chooses to display the elements on.

Comment: Running this from the Linux command line, I get a nice horizontal list.

Comment: You can probably turn it to string like print(', '.join(create_board()))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is caused by [pretty printing](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html), which is turned on by default in IPython sessions. This can be turned off in the configuration options, or during the session itself by running the [`pprint`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pprint) magic:

```
In [12]: %pprint
Pretty printing has been turned OFF

In [13]: %pprint
Pretty printing has been turned ON

In [14]: %pprint
Pretty printing has been turned OFF
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, maybe I did not understand, but if the goal is to print all the elements of the list on one line, regardless of the algorithm, might be enough to make you a join of the elements in the list?

so:

```
print(",".join(create_board()))
```

if we really are paranoid:

```
print(",".join([str(i) for i in create_board()]))
```